# Chromium don't display font that I selected

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, chromium

I have this problem **"Font that I selected in css don't work in chromium."**
First I write my code on windows.It a web app that will show environment values I use font 'Comic Sans MS' It work fine in window google chrome

[image: Screen on window]

but when I try to run this code on **raspberry pi 3** - chromium browser

[image: screen on chromium]

So you see the font that display is normal font of chromium  and my code in html page is

```
h3{font-family: "Comic Sans MS";}
```

`p {font-family: "Comic Sans MS";font-size: large;}`

like this So I guess it not about the code.Maybe it about raspberry pi font but what do I know?

So I don't know what to do.If you read this and know how to fix it please help me!!!
!!!THANK YOU!!!

Comment: I once had this issue and the "fix" I did was to manually change the font of the browser.

Comment: I guess on your Chromium environment the font is not installed. You may try to link a resource file of font 'Comic Sans MS'

Comment: thank you very much for helping me.